# Spring exception in apache cxf rest service

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, exception, cxf

I was learning how to build a rest service using apache cxf and i followed a tutorial. but when i run the code i got following exception

> SEVERE: Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   Line 15 in XML document from class path resource
>   [com/example/rest/cxf.xml] is invalid; nested exception is
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 15; columnNumber: 55;
>   cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:404)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:92)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:123)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:422)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:352)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5003)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5517)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1574)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 15; columnNumber: 55;
>   cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.    at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:437)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:325)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1906)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:746)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:379)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:605)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3138)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:880)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:348)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
>     ... 22 more
>
> Oct 28, 2015 2:52:44 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
>   listenerStart SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to
>   listener instance of class
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   Line 15 in XML document from class path resource
>   [com/example/rest/cxf.xml] is invalid; nested exception is
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 15; columnNumber: 55;
>   cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:404)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:92)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:123)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:422)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:352)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5003)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5517)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1574)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 15; columnNumber: 55;
>   cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.    at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:437)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:325)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1906)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:746)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:379)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:605)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3138)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:880)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:348)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
>     ... 22 more

my cxf.xml file is like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs" 
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xsi:schemalocation=
           "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans      
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx  
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.2.xsd 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
            http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs 
            http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd">   

<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml">  
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-jaxrs-binding.xml">  
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml">  
<jaxrs:server address="/" id="connectionService">  

 <jaxrs:servicebeans>             
  <ref bean="order">    </ref></jaxrs:servicebeans> 

    <jaxrs:extensionmappings>    
    <entry key="xml" value="application/xml">   
    </entry></jaxrs:extensionmappings>  
    </jaxrs:server> <bean class="com.example.rest.OrderInfoImpl" id="order">
    </bean>

    </import></import></import></beans>
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Is that Spring beans definition you posted your Cxf.xml? If so you're also importing a Cxf.xml, you could be importing itself which may be confusing Spring.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared jaxrs beans inside import class which is wrong, Here is updated beans.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs" 
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
       xsi:schemalocation=
           "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans      
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx  
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.2.xsd 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
            http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs 
            http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd">   

    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-jaxrs-binding.xml" /> 
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />

    <jaxrs:server address="/" id="connectionService">  
        <jaxrs:servicebeans>             
            <ref bean="order">    
            </ref>
        </jaxrs:servicebeans> 
        <jaxrs:extensionmappings> 
            <entry key="xml" value="application/xml"></entry>
        </jaxrs:extensionmappings>  
    </jaxrs:server> 

    <bean class="com.example.rest.OrderInfoImpl" id="order" />
</beans>
```